# How can i specify window width in my jquery code

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
            $("#divContent").css({ "top": "11.2%", "width": "18.4%", "position": "fixed", "z-index": "2" });
            $("#divChapters").css({ "position": "relative", "margin-left": "0%" });
        } else {
            $("#divContent").css({ "position": "relative", "width": "100%", "z-index": "0" });
            $("#divChapters").css({ "position": "relative", "margin-left": "0%" });
        }
```

this is my code where i am adding some css based on scrollTop > 0 but now i want some modifications as per my requirements, in my scrollTop function i want to detect the window width if it detect window width size = 1920 then i want to add width to this ID #divContent to be set as 11%. 
 Please help me.

Comment: Here's a start - http://jsfiddle.net/pz32ak0j/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
var width = window.innerWidth;

if(width==1920)
{
   $("#divContent").css({"width" : "11%"});
}
```

A cross-browser solution (using clientWidth and clientHeight for IE8 and earlier):

```
var w = window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth;

var h = window.innerHeight
|| document.documentElement.clientHeight
|| document.body.clientHeight;
```

**[SOURCE](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

use can use

```
$( window ).width();//get the width of wondow
$("#div1").width();//get the height of div
```

and you can ckeck your condition with using

```
$(window).width() = 1920
```